# How to take PostgreSQL database backup using Java

Tags: java, linux, postgresql

I want to use a PostgreSQL db for backup using java.
I've tried with the below code but I am getting:

> error pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is " postgres") Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p;
ProcessBuilder pb;
r = Runtime.getRuntime();
pb = new ProcessBuilder( 
        "/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_dump",
        "--host", "localhost",
        "--port", "5432",
        "--username", "postgres",
        "--dbname", "postfixdb",
        "--role", "postgres",
        "--password"," postgres",
        "--verbose",
       "/usr/pg_dump.backup");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
p = pb.start();
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String ll;
while ((ll = br.readLine()) != null) { System.out.println(ll); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consult [the `psql` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) for the invocation syntax and a list of allowed options.

Try to run it on the command line first, and only when that succeeds, try to run it from Java.

A list ob obvious mistakes:

- The option for “user” is `-U` (capitalized).
- `-p` is for the TCP port number.
- There is no `-B` option.
- There is no `-r` option.

Comment: I tryed this same code in windos for mysql, in their this code is working but here not. these both having different syntax?

Comment: Yes, because they are different programs. MySQL is not the same as PostgreSQL.

Comment: Bro, I tryed this new code here creating backup file but empty and line reader not executing. only upto "aaaa" printing in console.